# Getting some mess when trying to "draw" a textgrid file in Praat

Tags: phonetics, praat

I created a textgrid file that looks like this:

[image]

Then when I select the audio file together with the textgrid file and click "Draw", I'm getting not what everyone would expect. I'm getting this:

[image]

Why am I getting this mess? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Partial answer: always erase first.

Comment: @user6726 Thank you, I think this is a complete answer, everything looks fine after erasing and drawing. I just started using Praat and I had no idea I had to erase first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pursuant to comments: whenever you use Draw in Praat, always Erase first, since otherwise it uses the previous drawing.